# Modify exe resource using Java?

Tags: java, c++, winapi, java-native-interface, exe

I need to modify the string table of a win32 exe using Java.  I'm wondering if a library that does this exists, free or otherwise.

If there is no existing lib, how should I go about doing this?  Should I use JNI to call the win32 api functions (BeginUpdateResource, etc)?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use JNI to directly call UpdateResource APIs or you might want to consider using some of the .NET code ([like the one here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/updatestringresource.aspx)) that you can wrap into an assembly and use something like [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) to make the request. That might reduce the complexity of the code you need to write. Give it a shot.. :)